# C# code displaying all lines until you found that search word from your textbox

Tags: arrays, string, while-loop, textbox, indexoutofboundsexception

```
string[] hay = GetAllLines(filename); 
string needle = txtToonTotTekst.Text; 
string alertmsg = "";
string msg = "";
int keywordfound = 0;
int lineno = 0;
while (lineno <= hay.Length) 
{
    msg += hay[lineno];//msg = msg + hay[lineno];
    lineno++;

    if ((hay[lineno].IndexOf(needle) == -1))
    {
        keywordfound = 0;
        continue;
    }
    else
    { /*this means search word was found */
        keywordfound = 1;
        alertmsg = msg;
        //if coffee found in search string 
    }

    if (keywordfound == 1)
    {
        alertmsg = msg;
    }
    lineno++;
}

if (alertmsg == "")
{
    alertmsg = "Keyword not found";
}

SchrijfUitvoer("Tekst tonen tot zoektekst + "txtToonTotTekst.Text, alertmsg);
```

My question is about error saying index was outside the bounds of array.....normally it display the text from text file when you put a word to search and it display the lines upto when the search word have found

Comment: Can you provide the error message? What line is it pointing at (stack trace)?

Comment: if ((hay[lineno].IndexOf(needle) == -1))

Comment: hay[] is an array

Answer (score 0):

You have lineno++ two times, I guess it should be only one time at the end. Collections in C# are zero based, so:

```
while (lineno <= hay.Length)
```

should be:

```
while (lineno < hay.Length)
```

If Array has length 5, last element is [4]